# How to align two strings with letter-spacing

Tags: html, css

I want to make two string with different symbols count the same length.
The first letter of str 2 must be starting under first letter of str 1. The same for the last letters.

i.e.

```
<h1>123</h1> <!--one symbol more-->
<h1>12</h1>
```

I want:

```
<h1>123</h1> 
<h1>1 2</h1> <!--more letter-space-->
```

How can I get it dynamically with css for any string length? 
Maybe no need to use letter-spacing for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can initially have space between numbers then you can easily do this by reducing the letter spacing and justifying the text:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
}
.box h1 {
 text-align-last:justify;
 letter-spacing:-0.1em;
 
 margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>1 2 3</h1>
  <h1>1 2</h1>
  <h1>1 2 4 5</h1>
</div>
<h1>1245</h1>
```

Comment: Why you using are:
1) display inline-block if div element by default has a block display?
2) letter-spacing: -0.1 em?

Comment: @salius (1) inline-block to make its width fit the longest word and thus all the h1 will be equal to the longest word (2) the value of the letter spacing is an approximatiion of what you need to use to remove the space I have added. To make `1 2 4 5` show the same as `1245`: https://jsfiddle.net/u648a0sg/ (you may adjust the value based on your real use case)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be something like this:

```
123
1 2
```

here is something that will work:
HTML

```html
<h1>123</h1>
<h1 class="spacing">12</h1>
```

CSS:

```css
.spacing{
  letter-spacing:14px;
}
```

H1 letters are about 14 pixels wide.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javascript function and append the data to the element with reference id.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JavaScript by splitting the inner text and adding spaces then joining again, but if you want to stick with html and css only i will suggest you to add spans in the h1 and give them margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-breaking space `&nbsp` in HTML

```
<h1>123</h1>
<h1>1&nbsp&nbsp3</h1>
```

Use twice for character space.

**Preview**

## 123

## 1  3